# Should each php file contain only one object

Tags: php, oop, documentation

I am interested in OOP php. There are a lot of tutorials of creating classes, but didn`t find good explanation of the web based php OOP.What I mean is:

1. Should each php class be in different file(I think it must be, but some people tell me that even if all classes are in in one file the compiler will take only the part it need, but there will be bigger delay than including like the previous way)
2. Should each php file contain only one object, and this object execute only one function with parameters from the POST or GET request?

My goal is to make proper documentation - how the code should be written to be able to be documented easily?

Comment: One class per PHP file; generally speaking, yes. I highly recommend looking into the MVC pattern. As for the POST/GET question; imagine a situation in which you need to re-use the class but cannot supply POST/GET parameters. The class and it's function should be built to accept input rather than assuming to always receive a POST/GET.

Comment: When each class has its own php file, you can take advantage of auto-loading of the classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: It would be better to check yourself. Create a `php` file and check all things by your own. It will not take lot of time and you will get more clarification. Also if you have any doubt then put your code and ask

Answer (score 3):

1 - Yes. Each class should live in its own file. This facilitates many things, like naming those files (using the class name), SRP and most importantly, auto-loading.

2 - In here I disagree. Each file should deal with as many objects of as many types as it needs to. Each domain and the classes that represent its business rules are different, so it really depends on the concrete project that you're working on. Don't be scared of manipulating many different objects in a single PHP file. Just make sure that the class itself is cohesive and it doesn't do too many things. Keep things simple and try to stick to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I think that the best place to start getting lots of answers to these kind of questions is in the [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) website. In here there's lots of documentation about standards, documentation, auto-loading, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1 - You can have multiple classes in the same file. No problem with that at all. However, you can chose to do it with one class per file if it helps to get you your code better organized.

2 - Same. However, if you want to do things that way, you are going to have thousands of files in a large project. Not a good choice.

Take a look at phpdoc.org

and this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118

Some PHP IDEs have tools to automise and do a proper documentation. Check PHPStorms for example. Its one of the best PHP IDE's and has great documentation tools.